# Download and Store Files With Appcelerator TItanium or PhoneGap

Tags: download, cordova, store, titanium, appcelerator

I`d like to know if is possible to download PDF files and store them locally, with those frameworks. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible with both frameworks.

Comment: can you explain me? in phonegap? which api i should use?

Comment: Please provide examples in both frameworks, if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

you can use the new phonegap 1.3 download function to download the files ..
but you have to be careful since this function is still new an many people complain about it ..
this one is a universal one which will work on both android and iPhone or any other supported device ..